# error updating my barchart using d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I came through this problem just when I though I had d3 undercontrol... I can't find out why my code is crashing when I update my barChart using an empty array of data...

here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple tables in D3</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        
        .chart rect {
            fill: steelblue;
        }

        .axis path,
        .axis line {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #000;
            shape-rendering: crispEdges;
        }

        .x.axis path {
            display: none;
        }

        .axis {
            font: 10px sans-serif;
        }
      
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <svg class="chart">
    </svg>

    <script>
        var scanCounters = JSON.parse("[{\"scan\":\"111\",\"repetition\":3},{\"scan\":\"222\",\"repetition\":2},{\"scan\":\"333\",\"repetition\":4},{\"scan\":\"123\",\"repetition\":2},{\"scan\":\"456\",\"repetition\":1},{\"scan\":\"789\",\"repetition\":1}]");

        var scanCounters2 = JSON.parse("[{\"scan\":\"111\",\"repetition\":8},{\"scan\":\"222\",\"repetition\":6},{\"scan\":\"333\",\"repetition\":5},{\"scan\":\"123\",\"repetition\":3}]");

        var scanCounters3 = JSON.parse("[]");
        
        var columns = ["scan", "repetition"];

        var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 40};

        var width = 960;
        var height = 500;

        var innerWidth = width - margin.left - margin.right;
        var innerHeight = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var bcScan = barChart(600, 400, "chart");
        bcScan.update(scanCounters);

        setTimeout(function(){
            bcScan.update(scanCounters2);
            }, 1000);

        setTimeout(function(){
            bcScan.update(scanCounters3);
            }, 2000);

    function barChart(w, h, node) {

        var bC = {};

        var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
                width = w - margin.left - margin.right,
                height = h - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
                .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

        var y = d3.scale.linear()
                .range([height, 0]);

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(x)
                .orient("bottom");

        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(y)
                .orient("left");

        var svg = d3.select("." + node)
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");

        svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .append("text")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr("y", -40)
                .attr("dy", ".71em")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .text("Frequency");

        bC.update = function(data) {

            x.domain(data.map(function (d) {
                return d[Object.keys(d)[0]];
            }));
            y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
                return d[Object.keys(d)[1]];
            })]);

            svg.select(".x.axis")
                    .transition()
                    .duration(300).call(xAxis)
                    .selectAll("text")
                    .style("text-anchor", "end")
                    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
                    .attr("dy", ".15em")
                    .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)");

            svg.select(".y.axis")
                    .transition()
                    .duration(300)
                    .call(yAxis);

            var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar").data(data, function (d) {
                return d[Object.keys(d)[0]];
            });

            bars.exit()
                    .transition()
                    .duration(300)
                    .attr("y", y(0))
                    .attr("height", height - y(0))
                    .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6)
                    .remove();

            bars.enter()
                    .append("rect")
                    .attr("class", "bar")
                    .attr("y", y(0))
                    .attr("height", height - y(0));

            var trans = bars.transition().duration(300).attr("x", function (d) {
                return x(d[Object.keys(d)[0]]);
            });

            trans.attr("width", x.rangeBand())
                    .attr("y", function (d) {
                        return y(d[Object.keys(d)[1]]);
                    })
                    .attr("height", function (d) {
                        return height - y(d[Object.keys(d)[1]]);
                    });

        };

        return bC;
    }

        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is when I call `bcScan.update(scanCounters3);` where scanCounters3 is an empty array.

This is the error message:

> Error: Invalid value for  attribute height="NaN"
>
> Error: Invalid value for  attribute y="NaN"

**QUESTON:** Could someone help me to understand why it is crashing?

thanks

Comment: I assume the problem is that if there is no data your y domain will be empty? Put a check at the beginning of your update function. If data is empty, just bail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@EthanJewett, is correct, if you look at your `y.domain()` on each iteration you get:

```
[0, 4]
[0, 8]
[0, NaN]
```

So on your last iteration, your exit transition is doing math on an `NaN`:

```
.attr("y", y(0))
.attr("height", height - y(0))
```

I would just drop those lines altogether and make the exit transition:

```
       bars.exit()
         .transition()
         .duration(300)
         .style('fill-opacity', 1e-6)
         .remove();
```